# Going from monthly average dataframe to an interpolated daily timeseries

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, interpolation

I am interested in taking average monthly values, for each month, and set the monthly average values to be the value on the 15th day of each month (within a daily timeseries).

I start with the following (these are the monthly average values I am given):

`m_avg = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['1.527013956', '1.899169054', '1.669356146','1.44920871', '1.188557788', '1.017035727', '0.950243755', '1.022453993', '1.203913739', '1.369545041','1.441827406','1.48621651']`

EDIT:  I added one more value to the dataframe so that there are now 12 values.

Next, I want to put each of these monthly values on the 15th day (within each month) for the following time period:

```
ts = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1950', end='12/31/1999', freq='D')
```

I know how to pull out the date on 15th day of an already existing daily timeseries by using:

```
df= df.loc[(df.index.day==15)] # Where df is any daily timeseries
```

Lastly, I know how to interpolate the values once I have the average monthly values on the 15th day of each month, using:

```
df.loc[:, ['Col1']] = df.loc[:, ['Col1']].interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='both', limit=100)
```

How do I get from the monthly DataFrame to an interpolated daily DataFrame, where I linearly interpolate between the 15th day of each month, which is the monthly value of my original DataFrame by construction?

**EDIT:**

Your suggestion to use np.tile() was good, but I ended up needing to do this for multiple columns.  Instead of np.tile, I used:

```
index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1950', end='12/31/1999', freq='MS')
m_avg = pd.concat([month]*49,axis=0).set_index(index)
```

There may be a better solution out there, but this is working for my needs so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# monthly averages, note these should be cast to float 
month = np.array(['1.527013956', '1.899169054', '1.669356146', 
                  '1.44920871',  '1.188557788', '1.017035727',
                  '0.950243755', '1.022453993', '1.203913739', 
                  '1.369545041', '1.441827406', '1.48621651'], dtype='float')

# expand this to 51 years, with the same monthly averages repeating each year
# (obviously not very efficient, probably there are better ways to attack the problem, 
# but this was the question)
month = np.tile(month, 51)

# create DataFrame with these values
m_avg = pd.DataFrame({'Month': month})

# set the date index to the desired time period
m_avg.index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1950', end='12/1/2000', freq='MS')

# shift the index by 14 days to get the 15th of each month
m_avg = m_avg.tshift(14, freq='D')

# expand the index to daily frequency
daily = m_avg.asfreq(freq='D')

# interpolate (linearly) the missing values
daily = daily.interpolate()

# show result
display(daily)
```

Output:

```
            Month
1950-01-15  1.527014
1950-01-16  1.539019
1950-01-17  1.551024
1950-01-18  1.563029
1950-01-19  1.575034
...         ...
2000-12-11  1.480298
2000-12-12  1.481778
2000-12-13  1.483257
2000-12-14  1.484737
2000-12-15  1.486217

18598 rows × 1 columns
```

Comment: This works for 1950, but how do I get this to work for all years through 2000?

Comment: You just start with more data and change the `date_range` input accordingly. The rest of the code should then work just as well.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if there is a way to apply what you did in step one to 1950-2000, with the same monthly values taking the place of each month in the timeseries?  Would I need to create a dummy timeseries and and then broadcast the monthly average data to the daily timeseries?

Comment: Oh, the monthly averages are the same each year? But then the interpolated values are the same too (except for a slight deviation in leap years). So you could just replicate the resulting 1950 dataframe 50 times, or better, to account for leap years, extend the approach above to 1950-1953 and then replicate. In the end, you can reset the index to the date range you want. Less efficient but more convenient would be to just start with all the average values expanded to 50 years and let all the interpolations run repeatedly. I'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: I am guessing you had to do the first steps in numpy because pandas doesnt have a built in function to carry out this operation?  All in all, this worked well and was a helpful explanation.  Thank you for taking on this question; I appreciate your help in clarifying this for me!

Comment: You could also do it entirely with Pandas, e.g. using `pd.concat()`, but it's good to use NumPy for the basic stuff as it tends to be faster. In this case, handling a basic array is more efficient than handling an entire DataFrame. And it's not like this would mean introducing an additional library, since Pandas is built on top of NumPy. Anyway, thank you for your feedback, I'm glad I could help.